# what does "isRoaming" in the Wifip2p networkinfo mean?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

What is the meaning of isRoaming in Wifip2p network info mean?
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isRoaming()]
 It tells that usage of data on that network may incur extra charges? Which data is it refering to and how the usage will lead to extra charges?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're outside your home country/state and you turn on the phone it will automatically establish a GSM connection to the roaming partner network -> `TelephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming()` will return true. If data roaming is disabled or 'use only 2g' is enabled `NetworkInfo.isRoaming()` will return `false`, because no data connection is established. If you switch data services on `NetworkInfo.isRoaming()` will return true as well, since now both (GSM and data connection) are established and in roaming mode.

Hence, setting data-roaming on/off will make `NetworkInfo.isRoaming() return true/false`.

UPD: It is used when one wants to know whether the user has enabled Data on Roaming while on 2G/3G network.

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
//[edit: check for null]
if(ni != null) {
  //...Here check if this is connected and available...
  if (ni.isRoaming())
  {
      // user has enabled data even while he is on Roaming!!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since he asked specifically about Wifi P2P the correct answer that this will be an unused field as roaming only applied to cellular network and does not apply to Wifi P2P network information.

The only fields of networkinfo you should be using concerning wifi P2P is: isConnected (after which you normally request the connection info from the wifip2pmanager).